# DataTables saveState in database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to create an interactive table for my website. What i need is that every time a user is making a change at his table the state of the table([Save State](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)) will be saved in my db and next time he visits he will have the table with his changes (each user has an account)

I tried the code below but it doesn't save the changes in the db as it should do. (the changes' column is empty). I am also getting an error message in the dev tools (see below the code). Any hints why this is happening?

```
"stateSave": true,
'stateSaveParams.dt': function(e, settings, data) {
   data.search.search = "";
},
//SaveState
'stateSaveCallback': function(settings, data) {;
   $.ajax({
      'url': 'saveDtableState.php',
      'data': {
         name: 'resultsTable',
         data: data
      },
      'dataType': 'json',
      'method': 'POST',
      "success": function() {
         console.log()
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         console.log(thrownError);
      }
   });    
}
```

**Error Message**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Qb (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

**EDIT: Backend code**

```
$dataTable_name = $_POST['name'];
$dataTable_state = $_POST['state'];
$userID = 'random1';

if(!empty($userID)){
  $stateSave_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table_name (userID, dtable_name, dtable_state) VALUES ('$userID', '$dataTable_name', '$dataTable_state') ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It seems to me your backend is not working; "*Unexpected end of JSON input*" indicates malformed JSON or no response content at all. Besides that, remove `.dt` from `stateSaveParams.dt`, it is a callback, not an event with a namespace.

Comment: @davidkonrad I updated my post and included the backend. The other columns are getting filled tho.. just the column with the table's state doesn't

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to parse a data which is not valid json object in actual. please check your json parse method data.